# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' in Spyder IDE, even after I have successfully installed opencv library using anaconda in my windows pc

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, spyder, dlib

I have successfully installed opencv and dlib in my windows pc following this site:
https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-3-and-dlib-on-windows-python-only/
I have checked the version of opencv and dlib in cmd which make me sure that these libraries are installed in my windows pc.
[Version checking in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTNIG.png)

Now I open spyder which was installed by anaconda as default and I imported cv2 and dlib. But it gives error as no module named cv2 found, no module named dlib found.

Which step am I missing here? I am just a starter in programming world. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please read [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to understand how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run Spyder in the same virtual env as you are running your Python instance, in the screenshot.

You can do that by first installing Spyder in the virtual env, like so,

1. `activate opencv-env`
2. `conda install spyder`

and then calling the `spyder` executable from the same console.

That should do the trick.

Comment: When i installed anaconda, it automatically installed spyder. So, I tried starting that default spyder from same virtual env, but it did not work. But I tried your solution by installing spyder and it worked. Thanks